# How to align images in tableView

Tags: xcode, image, alignment, tableview

Now I have such view

[image]

How can I align images to center so all label will begin at 1 point like this?

[image]

I tried to change image size using Automator but result did not satisfied me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use auto-layout.

Or remove auto-layout (if it doesn't work) and set UIImageView in position where you want, like:

```
imageView.center = CGPointMake(x,y);
```

And manually set frame UILabel, like:

```
label.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
```

P/s: I think you have the problem with auto-layout